# Column type in case of value can be NULL or Full date time?

Tags: mysql, database, types, schema

I am using an API and its returning date value sometime complete date time, sometime unset or null.

In my mysql table I have set the column type to datetime but as date is not coming as expected and I cannot save a default time to it.

The question is what data type I should use for the column and will it be a good practice to enter 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and another column date_not_found

Comment: Set some default value for that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the column as nullable:

```
CREATE TABLE ...(
    ApiDate DATETIME NULL
)
```

So that you can insert `NULL` values, whenever you receive it from your `API`.

> will it be a good practice to enter 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and another
>   column date_not_found

Of course, the best practice is to have the **actual value** of `TIMESTAMP`. But it will still depend on how you are going to use the records. Is time crucial when you need to filter records between two dates? Do you need to convert the date and time for specific time zones of your users?